# JavaScript: Adding properties to a sealed object should throw a typeerror exception?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Suppose I've got something like this in JavaScript:

```
var obj = { name: "Luis" };
Object.seal( obj );

obj.address = "Fx"; //what should happen here?
```

So, what's the correct behavior? It's not in strict-mode, so I assumed that obj.address line would simply be ignored. However, that is not the case since it throws in Chrome. I'm looking at the tests for V8 and it seems like it should only throw in strict-mode:

object.seal test code:     http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/test/mjsunit/object-seal.js?spec=svn7379&r=7379

and here's some code from that file:

```
Object.seal(obj);

// Make sure we are no longer extensible.
assertFalse(Object.isExtensible(obj));
assertTrue(Object.isSealed(obj));

// We should not be frozen, since we are still able to
// update values.
assertFalse(Object.isFrozen(obj));

// We should not allow new properties to be added.
obj.foo = 42;
assertEquals(obj.foo, undefined);
```

btw, there are the tests from strict mode, where my example will clearly throw: http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/test/mjsunit/strict-mode.js?spec=svn7250&r=7250

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think that it shouldn't throw in non-strict code?

Comment: Take a look at kangax's link to the commented spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.seal` does 2 things.

1) Sets objects's internal [[Extensible]] attribute to false.

2) Iterates over all of object's own properties and sets their internal [[Configurable]] attribute to false.

This pretty much means that you **can't add any properties** to an object after it's being sealed. Note that existing **properties can still be modified**, as long as an object is not frozen (or if a property that's being assigned to is not made **non-writable explicitly**).

In your case, you're adding another property to a sealed object, so in ES5-non-strict it should be **ignored** whereas in ES5-strict it should result in **TypeError** (as you can see from [11.3.1 (Simple Assignment)](http://es5.github.com/#x11.13.1); more specifically you can track it down to [[CanPut]] which pretty much returns the value of [[Extensible]] — false — in this case, and then [[Put]] either throws, if it's strict mode, or doesn't).

So nope, Chrome should not be throwing here (in non-strict mode).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I went into the specs and understood how [[canput]] and [[put]] worked. the problem was finding the way [[put]] gets called in non-strict mode (because the exception throwing is determined by the last parameter that gets passed to it). btw, the annotated version really help here! thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

IE9: doesn't throw
Chrome: throws
Firefox 4: trows only in strict-mode code